# Jquery - JavaScript - mouseleave ignoring childs of the "toElement" property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mouseleave

What I have is this:

```
<body>
    <div id="containerCentral">
        <div id="headerSkinHitArea"></div>
        <div id="footerSkinHitArea"></div>
        <div id="headerSkin">
            <div id="botaoHomeSkin">
                <img src="images/botaoHome.png">
            </div>
            <div id="botaoFecharSkin">
                <img src="images/botaoFechar.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="conteudoSkin">
            <img src="images/fundo.png">
        </div>
        <div id="footerSkin">
            <div id="centroFooterSkin">
                <div id="botaoRetrocederSkin">
                    <img src="images/botaoSeta.png">
                </div>

                <div id="paginacaoSkin">

                </div>
                <div id="botaoAvancarSkin">
                    <img src="images/botaoSeta.png">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Through the JS and JQuery I detect the `mouseenter` in the `div` HITAREA. But when you go through the div `headerSkin` you just `mouseleave` the hit area.

On this event you have the `toElement` property. But the problem is, when you go out on top of a `button (childs)` of the `headerSkin`, the `toElement` is that element, not the `headerSkin`. So I don't have how to check if u leave to one or another.

What I want is test if the `mouseleave` from `hitarea` was for the `headerSkin` ignoring the childs.

There's a way to do it?

I try a thousand things with `mouseover, .is(":hover")` and other `ifs` but nothing works :/

On the internet there's a thousand of ways to test `isHover` but none works right like I want.

I tried with `mouse position` too, but I think keep tracking the mouse ALL the time is a little too much process no?!?!?

EDIT: Here what I did:

```js
$(document).ready( documentReady );

//Função executada quando o documento está pronto para ser usado
function documentReady()
{
 //Seta um listener que roda a função assim que o quando o iFrame for carregado
 $("#mainContentContainerSkin").on( "load" , iFrameReady );

 //Adiciona os listeners de mouseover as duas hit areas no topo e na base da página
 $('.skinHitAreas').on( "mouseenter" , showHideMenusSkinTest );

 //Esconde o menu 1 segundo após iniciar a página
 setTimeout( "showHideMenusSkin( false )" , 1000 );

 $(window).resize( mainWindowResizeEvent );
}

function iFrameReady()
{
 $("#mainContentContainerSkin").off( "load" , iFrameReady );
}

/**
 * [Testa o tipo de evento para saber se deve ou não esconder ou mostrar os menus do header e do footer.]
 * @param  {[Event]} event [Evento contendo as informações do memso.]
 */
function showHideMenusSkinTest( event )
{
 //Testa se o evento foi de mouseenter ou mouseleave
 if ( event.type == "mouseenter" )
 {
  //Remove o listener de mouseenter e adiciona o de mouseleave
  $('.skinHitAreas').off( "mouseenter" , showHideMenusSkinTest );
  $('.skinHitAreas').on( "mouseleave" , showHideMenusSkinTest );
  
  //Mostra os menus
  showHideMenusSkin( true );
 }
 else if( event.type == "mouseleave" )
 {
  //Testa se o mouse está na área de um dos menus quando sai da hit area, caso esteja não executa a função de esconder os menus.
  if ( event.clientY >= $(" #headerSkin").height() && event.clientY <= $(window).height() - $("#footerSkin").height() || event.clientY < 0 || event.clientY >= $(window).height() )
  {
   //Remove o listener de mouseleave e adiciona o de mouseenter
   $('.skinHitAreas').off( "mouseleave" , showHideMenusSkinTest );
   $('.skinHitAreas').on( "mouseenter" , showHideMenusSkinTest );
   
   //Esconde os menus
   showHideMenusSkin( false );
  }
 }
}

/**
 * [Esconde ou mostra os menus do header e do footer]
 * @param  {[Boolean]} p_showHide [Boleano que define se deve mostrar (TRUE) ou esconder (FALSE) o menu.]
 */
function showHideMenusSkin( p_showHide )
{ 
 TweenLite.killTweensOf( $("#headerSkin") );
 TweenLite.killTweensOf( $("#footerSkin") );

 if ( p_showHide )
 {
  $("#headerSkin").css( "display" , "block" );
  $("#footerSkin").css( "display" , "block" );
  
  TweenLite.to( $("#headerSkin") , 1 , { top : 0 } );
  TweenLite.to( $("#footerSkin") , 1 , { bottom : 0 } );
  TweenLite.to( $("#mainContentContainerSkin") , 1 , { css : { marginTop : 56 , height : $(window).height() - 112 } } );
 }
 else
 {
  TweenLite.to( $("#headerSkin") , 1 , { top : -56 , display : "none" } );
  TweenLite.to( $("#footerSkin") , 1 , { bottom : -56 , display : "none" } );
  TweenLite.to( $("#mainContentContainerSkin") , 1 , { css : { marginTop : 0 , height : $(window).height() } } );
 }
}

function mainWindowResizeEvent()
{
 
}
```

```css
body
{
 font-family: "gudearegular";
 margin: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

div.customButton
{
 cursor: pointer;
}

#mainContainerSkin
{
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0 auto;
}

#headerSkin
{
 position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 54px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #EDEDED;
}

#footerSkin
{
 position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 54px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #EDEDED;
}

#closeButtonSkin
{
 width: 54px;
    height: 54px;
    float: right;
    border-left: 1px;
 border-right: 0px;
 border-top: 0px;
 border-bottom: 0px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #EDEDED;
 background-image: url( "../img/botaoFechar.png" );
}

#centerBoxFooterSkin
{
 width: 166px;
 height: 54px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border-left: 1px;
 border-right: 1px;
 border-top: 0px;
 border-bottom: 0px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #EDEDED;
}

#pagesBoxFooterSkin
{
 width: 54px;
 height: 54px;
 float: left;
 border-left: 1px;
 border-right: 1px;
 border-top: 0px;
 border-bottom: 0px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #EDEDED;
}

#actualPageBoxFooterSkin
{
 margin-left: 5px;
 color: #666666;
 font-family: "gudeabold";
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: 700;
}

#pagesBoxSeparatorFooterSkin
{
 width: 56px;
 margin-top: 2px;
 margin-bottom: 2px;
 border-left: 0px;
 border-right: 0px;
 border-top: 0px;
 border-bottom: 1px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #666666;
 -ms-transform: rotate( -45deg ); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate( -45deg ); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate( -45deg );
}

#totalPagesBoxFooterSkin
{
 margin-right: 5px;
 color: #666666;
 float: right;
 font-family: "gudearegular";
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 700;
}

#nextPageButtonFooterSkin
{
 width: 54px;
    height: 54px;
    float: left;
    -ms-transform: rotate( 180deg ); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate( 180deg ); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate( 180deg );
    background-image: url( "../img/botaoSeta.png" );
}

#previousPageButtonFooterSkin
{
 width: 54px;
    height: 54px;
    float: left;
    background-image: url( "../img/botaoSeta.png" );
}

#mainContentContainerSkin
{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 border: 0px;
}

#headerSkinHitArea
{
 position: fixed;
 left: 0px;
 width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}

#footerSkinHitArea
{
 position: fixed;
 left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fonts.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/vivaskin.css">
    <script src="js/gsap/TweenMax.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/gsap/TimelineMax.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/gsap/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/gsap/easing/EasePack.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/VivaSkin.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mainContainerSkin">
      <div id="headerSkinHitArea" class="skinHitAreas"></div>
      <div id="footerSkinHitArea" class="skinHitAreas"></div>
      <div id="headerSkin">
        <div id="closeButtonSkin" class="customButton"></div>
      </div>
      <!-- ESSE CONTEÚDO SRC VIRÁ DO BANCO? DE ONDE VEM ESSA INFO? -->
      <iframe id="mainContentContainerSkin" src="clientes/1/curso_teste5/paginas/pagina01/index.html"></iframe>
      <div id="footerSkin">
        <div id="centerBoxFooterSkin">
          <div id="previousPageButtonFooterSkin" class="customButton"></div>
          <div id="pagesBoxFooterSkin">
            <!-- DE ONDE VEM ESSAS INFORMAÇÕES? -->
            <div id="actualPageBoxFooterSkin">01</div>
            <div id="pagesBoxSeparatorFooterSkin"></div>
            <div id="totalPagesBoxFooterSkin">15</div>
          </div>
          <div id="nextPageButtonFooterSkin" class="customButton"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Provide JavaScript code too. possibly JSfiddle would help a lot.

Comment: +1 provide a live example of your code on http://jsbin.com/ or else

Comment: I did it with this code, it's working. What u think guys?

Answer (score 0):

Use the mouseenter and mouseleave events in jquery. You will want to use them for both the parent div and child div. This is a simplified example that you can hopefully use for your needs:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dohover')
      .mouseenter(function(){
          //Do stuff when you enter parent
    })
      .mouseleave(function(){
          //undo stuff when you leave
    });
    $('.donthover')
      .mouseenter(function(){
          //Undo stuff in parent when you enter child
      })
      .mouseleave(function(){
          if($('.dohover').is(':hover')){
              //Do stuff in parent if you are hovering over it after leaving child
          }
      });
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ge9nuzn/), I just changed the parents color.